# If exactly one neuron magically disappeared from my brain, would my thoughts be significantly different?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, philosophy-of-mind

> If exactly one neuron magically disappeared from my brain, would my thoughts be significantly different?

One can ask an analogous question about a single neuron (and/or its synapses) being magically displaced.

I would like to know how ["sensitive to initial conditions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) or, rather, to fine details of structure is the activity of human brain.

This could lead to a philosophy of mind version of the old [ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) philosophical thought experiment.

Also:

> Has this version of the ship of theseus already appeared in the philosophy of mind literature?

Comment: Your brain has neurons that are dying every minute. Ask yourself if your thoughts are significantly different in the time it took to read my sentence.